# How to add a field to an array in Typscript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I want to add a new field to the array list, for example
array [2]={id:"123232", stock_title:"MAH-1234",stock_count:"3"}
[image: array debug image]
It's very simple but I can't find it, I need only add input value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) for how to add array items in Javascript

Comment: no, i need to add a field to an existing item, not to add a new item

Comment: you have an array of dictionaries. So indexing the array gives you a dictionary item. You can add an item to the dictionary by just giving a new key. 

something like: array[2]["new_key"]="some value"